# How to fetch last message from all conversations with every other user from messages table?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.3

I am using laravel framework 5.3. I am getting a wrong result after executing query. I have two table one is user and other is message.Here is my scenario

```
enter code here
User table-

 id    name 
  1     a
  2     b
  3     c


Message table:
id   sender_id   receiver_id  message
 1     1             2          hii
 2     2             1          hello
 3     1             3          hiiii
```

Now I want to fetch the last message between those users having sender_id and receiver_id 
here is my code:-

```
enter code here
$coreQueryUser=DB::select(
        '
            select m.* ,u.*
            from
                messages m
                inner join (
                select max(id) as maxid
                from messages
                where messages.sender_id = 1 // here i am sending userid is 1
                group By (if(sender_id > receiver_id,  sender_id, receiver_id)), 
                (if(sender_id > receiver_id,  receiver_id, sender_id))
               ) t1 on m.id=t1.maxid 
                join 
                users u  ON u.id = (CASE WHEN m.sender_id = 1
                                   THEN m.sender_id
                                   ELSE m.receiver_id        
                               END)
        '
        );
```

Note- I want to find all the last messages that been with userid (1)
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ORDER BY` phrase and limit your results to **1** using `LIMIT`. 
My answer is assuming that `id` row is your **primary key** and it is **auto incremented**

**Edit of your code \**

```
enter code here
$coreQueryUser=DB::select(
    '
        select m.* ,u.*
        from
            messages m
            inner join (
            select max(id) as maxid
            from messages
            where messages.sender_id = 1 // here i am sending userid is 1
            group By (if(sender_id > receiver_id,  sender_id, receiver_id)), 
            (if(sender_id > receiver_id,  receiver_id, sender_id))
           ) t1 on m.id=t1.maxid 
            join 
            users u  ON u.id = (CASE WHEN m.sender_id = 1
                               THEN m.sender_id
                               ELSE m.receiver_id        
                           END)
        ORDER BY m.id DESC LIMIT 1
    '
    );
```

Comment: i want query like that it will fetch all conversations with last message where userid is 1